# Angular 10/11 adding ngx-sharebuttons getting "export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Tags: typescript, angular11

I am trying to add social media share buttons on my angular app - so i have seen this ngx-sharebuttons which seems to provide, what i would like to achieve.

However i cannot build my angular application if it use

npm i ngx-sharebuttons @angular/cdk

Version

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.2",
    "@ngx-markdown/core": "^0.2.2",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.32",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^11.1.0",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.5.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "firebase": "^8.7.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "justifiedGallery": "^3.8.1",
    "katex": "^0.13.16",
    "lightgallery": "^2.2.0-beta.0",
    "marked": "^3.0.2",
    "mermaid": "^8.12.0",
    "ng-recaptcha3": "^1.3.2",
    "ngx-autosize": "^1.8.4",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^14.0.1",
    "ngx-gallery-9": "^1.0.6",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-markdown": "^11.1.3",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.1.1",
    "ngx-sharebuttons": "^9.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^12.0.0-rc.1",
    "propper": "^1.0.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  }
```

Below is the angular version in use

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.14
Node: 14.16.1
OS: linux x64

Angular: 11.2.14
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... localize, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.14
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1102.14
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.14
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.14
@angular/cdk                    12.2.4
@angular/fire                   6.1.5
@schematics/angular             11.2.14
@schematics/update              0.1102.14
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.0.7
```

when building the app with "ng serve" I get the following errors

```
Error: ./node_modules/ngx-sharebuttons/fesm2015/ngx-sharebuttons-buttons.js 95:10-28
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-sharebuttons/fesm2015/ngx-sharebuttons-buttons.js 280:10-28
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-sharebuttons/fesm2015/ngx-sharebuttons-buttons.js 410:10-28
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
```

Am following this tutorial https://www.eduforbetterment.com/tag/social-share/

Comment: I posted a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69167595/getting-errors-in-angular-because-%C9%B5%C9%B5factorytarget-is-undefined

Comment: I am also seeing this issue when trying to use ngx-sharebuttons.

Answer (score 3):

you probably already solved this, but this is for all other people that may encounter this issue. Problem is due to the ngx-sharebuttons version, latest version is for Angular 12, in my case I am using Angular version 11 and had the same problem.

I solved it by installing ngx-sharebuttons version 8.0.5.

Hope this will help somebody.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I had to use the following version for it to work with angular version 10/11 "ngx-sharebuttons": "^8.0.1",  ```"ngx-sharebuttons": "^8.0.1"```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to check that the version of angular and the version of ngx-sharebuttons are compatible.

I am using angular 11 and the latest version of
ngx-sharebuttons not working, then I uninstalled that version and after installing version 8.1, I stopped and ran the server again and it works perfectly